# regex add questionmark as a character

Tags: regex

I try to create a simple regex with a question mark based on the following string:

> 22969152008377?_uw=2884713357351

There should be any number at the beginning, followed by `?_uw=` followed by any numbers. I am not able to add question mark to the regex. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just escape the question mark like this

```
\d*\?_uw=\d*
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vJ9pA0/1)